# Why isn't Riverpod allowing me to instantiate ProviderScope?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm working through the Riverpod documentation, starting with `ProviderScope` (from https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/providers).  But my app isn't a function so the last line is failing. How do I fix this pleas?

```dart
const app = MaterialApp
(
    title: Messages.Ordigi,
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: Routes.getRoutes,
);
runApp(ProviderScope(child: app()));  // ERROR: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app` is a `MaterialApp` and not a function so you shouldn't write `app()`

Setting passing it directly should work, try:

```
const app = MaterialApp
(
    title: Messages.Ordigi,
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: Routes.getRoutes,
);
runApp(ProviderScope(child: app));
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you added "flutter_riverpod" in your pubspec.yaml file and not just "riverpod".

This is a link to flutter_riverpod:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod